# Selecting lines using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file as below:

```
2015-05-08 09:02 Out.dat
2015-05-08 10:45:22.617 ERROR   EventLog
2015-05-08 10:02 Out.xml
2015-05-08 11:30 Out.html
2015-05-08 05:30 Out.ps
```

I am trying to select line containing 10 AM till it reached anything which is not 10 am. So I am using the below `sed` command:

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 10:/ , /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [^10]:/ p' test.dat
```

And the output is:

```
2015-05-08 10:45:22.617 ERROR   EventLog
2015-05-08 10:02 Out.xml
2015-05-08 11:30 Out.html
2015-05-08 05:30 Out.ps
```

I don't want the last line to come. It should stop at 11:30 line (3rd line of output).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Your problem is that `[^10]` matches anything that's not 1 OR 0, not "10".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/^[0-9-]* 10:/ !d' YourFile
```

- remove any line not having `10:` after the date
- use `-i` for inline editing (not streaming in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Without testing, I think what you want to do is omit the second term:

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 10:/ p' test.dat
```

In your example, the second term will "include" the line that matches it also. You only want to print the lines that *do* match, not a range between lines.

Basically it's just a `grep`.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I just realised that what you want to do is *include* the next line after. Your regex is fine except for "`[^10]:`" which "matches any value that is not `1` or `0`".

You could just put `1[^0]` ..

```
$ sed -rn '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 10:/ , /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 1[^0]:/ P' test.txt
2015-05-08 10:45:22.617 ERROR   EventLog
2015-05-08 10:02 Out.xml
2015-05-08 11:30 Out.html
```

Comment: sed is fine and grep a still better idea if no inline editing (or using temporary file)

Comment: What i want to do is select any line starting with 10 till any other line which does not have 10 in it. In this case it is 11 in other cases it might be something else. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

`[^10]:` matches anything that's not 1 or 0, i.e. a single character, followed by `:`, but such line is not present in your data.

It's hard to implement negation in sed. Fortunately, you don't need it:

```
sed -rn '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 10:/ p'
```